# Generify call to getter of an entity

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 hibernate entities (Java classes with @Entity annotation), which look like that:

```
@Entity
Employer {
    Long id; 
    String name; 
}
```

And

```
@Entity
Student {
    Long id; 
    String name;
}
```

I have several entries of each in the database, and I am converting both table entries into a maps using stream like:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId, Functions.identity()));
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employer::getId, Functions.identity()));
```

I want to generify these streams, so I need to only call one method. But the `::getId` part is not working with sample generic like T, since it could be any type. Is there a specific hibernate class I can `<T extend SpecificClass>` from?
Or only option would be to create my own interface that would have getId method and be implemented by both entity classes?

Comment: yeah, it seems that you need to create your own interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about something like:

```
interface Persistable<T>{ 

    T getId(); 

    void setId();
}
```

...so you can do something like:

```
Student implements Persistable<Long>{ 

    private Long id;
    ...

    @Overrides
    public Long getId(){ ... }

    @Overrides
    public void setId(Long id){ ... }
```

> „*...Is there a specific hibernate class...*“

I'm not 100% sure whether or not Hibernate itself has anything specific to it built-in. But as always, [*Spring's got you covered*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html):

---

*public interface **Persistable<ID>***

*Simple interface for entities.*

...

*ID getId()*

*Returns the id of the entity.*

...

If you want to go with Spring's *`Persistable`* — *but don't want to have to implement it's methods in a boatload of preexisting entities* — one way around it is to introduce a base class that implements *`Persistable`*...

---

```
public abstract class BasePersistable<T> implements Persistable<T>{ 

protected T id;

protected BasePersistable(T id){ 
    this.id = id;
}

public T getId(){ return this.id; }

public void setId(T id){  this.id = id; }
```

}

Then just have your entities extend that base class...

```
public class Foo extends BasePersistable<Long> { 

   public Foo(Long id){ super(id); }

   ...
   @Column(...)
   ...
}
```

That way, you only need to implement the *`Persistable`* API in one place.